# Slow connection to production MongoDB due to TLS handshake retransmits

Tags: ssl, mongodb, wireshark

I have question about something that had me tearing my hair out for the past two days.

Long story short: specifically over my home network, my connection to our work MongoDB is stupidly slow. Over my home network it takes around 40 seconds to load a page. When I switch to my mobile hotspot for example, it takes around 1 second (it is this fast as well when I go to a friends house with my laptop or use the office network as well).

Did some wiresharking, here is what is happening:

[Fast query sniff over my mobile network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F4GwI.png)

[Slow query sniff over my home network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ppBRR.png)

As you can see, the query information is sent whenever an SSL packet of length 329 is sent. For some reason, it takes around 40 seconds over my home network to get the packet with that length. Before that, there is a bunch of retransmissions of the same SSL packet that is length 149 which is never sent through a different network.

[Here is what the full message looks like (length = 329 in the screenshots)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XWKG1.png)

[Here is the repeating SSL message that only occurs through the home network (message length = 149 in the screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ndefy.png)

So the problem is indeed not with the query but with the stuff in between the first tcp hello/query request. As a side note, my home network speeds are pretty solid, its consistently above 150Mbps and pings are snappy.

I tried both wifi and ethernet with similar results. When talked to the ISP they said our building was old and our infrastructure here is sh*tty (yes, this is actually what they said) and there isn't anything specific with our account that would cause something like this. Any help or clues as to what might be a way of going about this would be very much appreciated. Thanks.

EDIT: fiddling with the MTU value on my router had no effect.

EDIT: wrangled pcapng files (5.5.5.5 is the server and 192... is my home desktop)

[fast mobile network pcapng drive link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XS4gtWpd9To4c--CEzFDZI1evkpFf8u5/view?usp=sharing)

[slow home network pcapng drive link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XS4gtWpd9To4c--CEzFDZI1evkpFf8u5/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: I am sorry but screen shots of the bed part are kind of useless. Better post the decoded packets structure.

Comment: @Robert I don't know why I haven't done this while posting but I added my wrangled pcapng's to the end of the post. Thank you for taking your time

Comment: just a wild guess, but does your ISP throttles your non-HTTP connections? try testing with VPN and/or serve a HTTP download page in 27017/tcp.

Comment: @mforsetti just tested we with a VPN, no changes, still slow. Given that, any clues what might be the problem? Could my router hardware for example be playing some part in this?